# Assigning value of arthimetic operation

Tags: bash

What is wrong with my code?
The code I used:

```bsh
a=4
b=$(expr $a % 2)
```

When I tried to display b

```
$b
Bash: 0: command not found
```

Should it be 0 alone? Because I have trouble in using `b` in `if` statement.

Comment: You want to use `echo $b` to display the value of `b`.

Comment: you can assign b in the arithmetic expansion directly *a=5; ((b = a % 2)); echo $b*

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it just that is not how you show the value of a variable.

```
$b
```

is just like entering the value of variable b and hitting enter as if that value was a bash command. That's why bash complains being unable to find the command "0".

Try this and see what happens:

```
x=ls
$ls
```

As the others said you can "show" the value of a variable b using

```
echo $b
```

Hope this helps.